# Debian 9.8 binding 2 mutliple IPs using Interfaces.d

Tags: networking, debian

I am trying to set up 2 ip addresses on interface enp0s25. I am using 3 right now just for troubleshooting purposes.

Here is my setup
this is the content of /etc/network/interfaces.d/enp0s25

```
auto enp0s25
auto enp0s25:0
auto enp0s25:1

iface enp0s25 inet static
      address 192.168.1.95
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.1.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

iface enp0s25:0 inet static
      address 192.168.1.96
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.1.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# This is the actual second ipaddress that I want
iface enp0s25:1 inet static
      address 172.16.28.250
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 172.16.28.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

This is the contents of /etc/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp0s25
# iface enp0s25 inet dhcp
```

When I do a `sudo service network restart` it fails
so then I do `sudo service network status` and I get

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-02-25 15:15:37 EST; 3min 8s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 481 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 477 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --lis
 Main PID: 481 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 25 15:15:37 trmi-ral-server systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Feb 25 15:15:37 trmi-ral-server ifup[481]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 25 15:15:37 trmi-ral-server ifup[481]: ifup: failed to bring up enp0s25:0
Feb 25 15:15:37 trmi-ral-server ifup[481]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 25 15:15:37 trmi-ral-server ifup[481]: ifup: failed to bring up enp0s25:1
Feb 25 15:15:37 trmi-ral-server systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 25 15:15:37 trmi-ral-server systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Feb 25 15:15:37 trmi-ral-server systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 25 15:15:37 trmi-ral-server systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

but if I restart, then **they work**.

`ip address` shows them all assigned.

I can ping them from another computer on both networks (swapping the ethernet cable between them)

**But**, `service networking status` still shows that it is failed.

how can I have `networking` not running but actually have network connectivity?

Comment: Try using :0, :1 and :2, not <blank> and :0?

Comment: Try not using :numbers at all? They're a 15-year-old relic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> service networking status still shows that it is failed.

The program doesn't tell you, but the failure message has nothing to do with your *addresses*; it is actually failing because you told it to configure the same route twice.

Yes, you can have two routes for the same network as long as they go over different interfaces. But you don't really have different interfaces; all you have is 3 entries for the same "enp0s25" interface. There is no such thing as "alias interfaces".

So your configuration file translates to these commands:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.95/24 dev enp0s25
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s25

ip addr add 192.168.1.96/24 dev enp0s25
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s25

ip addr add 172.16.28.250/24 dev enp0s25
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 172.16.28.1 dev enp0s25
```

Notice that the configuration asks the route for `0.0.0.0/0 ... dev enp0s25` to be added twice. The first attempt succeeds and gives you connectivity, the second attempt fails and crashes ifupdown (networking.service), the third attempt would do the same as well.

To avoid this, remove all `gateway...` lines except one.

(Note: Linux, by default, does not support per-subnet IPv4 gateways – if you add multiple default routes, it will just pick one and use it for *everything,* even if it's for the "wrong" subnet. So if `192.168.1.1` and `172.16.28.1` belong to the same router, you don't actually need to add both.)

The file, updated for Debian 9 syntax, would look like:

```
auto enp0s25

iface enp0s25 inet static
      address 192.168.1.95/24
      gateway 192.168.1.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

iface enp0s25 inet static
      address 192.168.1.96/24

iface enp0s25 inet static
      address 172.16.28.250/24
```

> how can I have networking not running but actually have network connectivity?

It's never "running" in the first place. It's just a script that configures the IP addresses and exits,  and that's all it does. The network is handled entirely by the Linux kernel itself.

Comment: what if the networks are not sharing a route and I simply want to be able to move it between the networks (my physically moving the ethernet cable. Then would it make sense to have a gateway for 172.16.28 address? or would Linux just always pick the first one?

Comment: It picks the one with lowest metric (which is kind of a "cost" parameter). To really have multiple gateways you'd need _policy routing_ via `ip rule` (or alternatively, in IPv6 only, source-specific routing)... or it'd be much better to keep the network profiles separate.